# Titanium: Why TabGroup's tabs does not Changing / Working?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have a tabGroup and it holds 3 tabs.

Code in **app.js:**

```
// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup(
{ 

//tabBarHidden:false
});

        var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        url:'TabClasses/Tab1/Tab1.js',
        navBarHidden:true                    
    });
    var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
        icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
        title:'Friend List',

        window:win1
    });

    var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({        
        url:'TabClasses/Tab2/SearchView.js'
    });
    var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
        icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
        title:'Search',

        window:win2
    });

    var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({            
        url:'TabClasses/Tab2/FindView.js'
    });
    var tab3 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
        icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
        title:'Places',
        window:win3
    });

//  add tabs

tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);
tabGroup.addTab(tab3);

loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if (true)
     {
        tabGroup.open
        ({
            transition: Titanium.UI.iPhone && Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT
        });
     } 
});
```

But when I click on different tabs , the tabs changes only once. Means when I click on tab 2 from tab 1 it changes but when I go back to tab 1 then it does not change and remains tab 2 's screen.

How can I solve this issue ?

Also it works Fine in Android !!!

Thanks...

Comment: If you put tabGroup.open(); outside the event what happens?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan : Does it matters ? I want to show tab bar if login get true.

Comment: Just wanted to know if normal behavior is working or not?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan : same behavior

Comment: It works for me, though i have commented out the window url.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: Actually I have created view in different files so I used url method. Is there any another approach to do the same ?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: So How can I call my view from another js file ???

Comment: No, your approach is right. Just try to debug the views.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan : I did it ... but.. can you put your code as an answer ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7376/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-maulik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create and open a new window in your .js file. You should use current window like

`var currentWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow`

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** :

There was a mistake in my code. I was creating new window in every .js (Tab1.js, Tab2.js and Tab3.js) file. Like :

```
var currentWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow;
 ({
     title:'A List',
     backgroundColor:'white',
     top:0,
     height:416
 });
```

instead of

```
var currentWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
```